# Why does this happen in a bat file?

Tags: position, comments

If I structure an IF statement as so:

`For %%X  in ("%TargetFile1%") Do Set "CurrentAttrib=%%~aX"`

`If Not "%CurrentAttrib:R=%"=="%CurrentAttrib%" (`

`color 4f`

`echo     *********************************************************************`

`echo:    F I L E   I S   O P E N   O N   A N O T H E R   C O M P U T E R`

`echo     *********************************************************************`

`echo:`

`echo:`

`(pause) & (exit))`

It works as expected.
If I add a comment as below:

`For %%X in ("%TargetFile1%") Do Set "CurrentAttrib=%%~aX"`

`If Not "%CurrentAttrib:R=%"=="%CurrentAttrib%" (`

`color 4f`

`echo *********************************************************************`

`echo: F I L E I S O P E N O N A N O T H E R C O M P U T E R`
`echo *********************************************************************`
`echo:`

`echo:`

`:: pause to read and exit`

`(pause) & (exit))`

It will immediately exit even if the IF statement isn't processed

If I add an echo: after the comment it will again work as expected.

Why does the comment position change the operation?

Comment: I am surprised that no one has a clue to this issue. Oh well. It must just be my computer.